# Submit Form with ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I successfully load iframe into div `#output` with AJAX. This script play video for me.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '.play_next' ).on('click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#output').empty();
        var meta_key = $( this ).data( 'meta-key' );
        var post_id = $( this ).data( 'post-id' );
        $.ajax( {
            url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                action : 'wpse_296903_call_meta',
                post_id : post_id,
                meta_key : meta_key,
            },
            success: function( result) {
                $( '#output' ).append( result );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

> Now no more need of `#output` in div, Need to submit this value with
>   form.

```
<form action="http://other-domain.com/" method="POST" target="_black">
    <input type="submit" name="iframe" value="" />
</form>
```

This form submit `iframe` to other domain, which open in new tab with property `target="_black`.

**How put `#output` value in Form and submit with Ajax?**

Comment: Are you trying to take data from within an iframe and submit it with ajax from outside of the iframe?

Comment: @mike510a No, collect all the value (which is just iframe). then submit it

Comment: @mike510a Give complete value to form and submit

Comment: It should be target=_blank not _black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit

You can not access the contents of an iframe from outside of one if its an iframe with a different origin.

If its the same origin

```
 let form = document.createElement('form');
 let input = document.createElement('input');
 input.type = 'hidden';
 input.value = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.innerHTML);
 input.name = 'iframe_data';
 form.action = 'myDestination.html'
 form.appendChild(input);
 document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

Comment: Only true if cross domain, otherwise you can

Comment: @mike510a sorry for late reply, Can you please update whole script. How insert ajax `#output` into Form `value` before submit?

Comment: is it an existing form ?

Comment: @mike510a Yes its an existing form